# Will the fastest time in dry weather be deleted when the weather changes to rainy?

Tags: formula-1

Imagine that in Q3, Valteri Bottas is the first car to release to the track and takes his first lap in dry weather while the other 9 drivers still not haven't got into the track yet. Then, after Bottas finishes his first lap, the weather changes from dry to wet and of course, the remaining drivers that still don't get a chance to get into the track need to change from slick to wet/intermediate tyres.

My question is, **will Bottas' time during dry weather get deleted due to changed weather?** I mean, Bottas' lap during dry weather could be outqualified by e.g. Verstappen during wet weather even though that is disadvantageous.

Answer (score 5):

No. Luck of the weather is just one of the hazards.

Teams typically try to plan on weather forecasts so they can get the best time possible, but sometimes they just don't get it quite right. And they have to deal with that - there is no penalisation of a driver/team for managing to be lucky with the weather.